# State of decay survivor mission count

Tags: state-of-decay

In State of Decay, how do I find out how many mission I have completed with a selected survivor?

I can't see to find that statistic. I am not sure if that is because I that statistic is not available to the user or that I have not

Answer (score 2):

From how much I play I believe it does not have this feature. I am not 100% but I play this game a lot and I seem to not find this feature anyway. Hope this helps

Comment: +1, I've played SoD and its expansions repeatedly, and have never seen this statistic.